# finding the maximum value between text and numbers for each timestep

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, max

I have the intention to find the maximum values for each rows under the TS in the input data for a very big data. This is the input data:

```
SCALAR
ND    3
ST  0
TS        10.00
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
SCALAR
ND    3
ST  0
TS      3600.47
255.1744
255.0201
257.0000
SCALAR
ND    3
ST  0
TS      7200.42
255.5984
255.4946
255.7014
SCALAR
ND    3
ST  0
TS      10000.0
256.5984
255.1946
255.7014
```

At the end I want to save the maximum values with the same format form different timesteps like following:

```
SCALAR
ND    3
ST  0
TS      0.00
**256.60**
**255.49**
**257.00**
```

I have written a code like this:

```
 from __future__ import print_function

 lines = []
 Newlist = []
 with open('data.txt') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     for line in f:
         lines.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
         lines1=list(enumerate(lines))
         list_n=list(zip(*(iter(lines),)*7))
         max_value = max(float(n) for n in list_n)
print(max_value, file=outfile)
```

The program works till the last line but the execution of the last line I get the following error : ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence. I don't know why.

I should mention that I've deleted a lot of numbers after TS to make this example small. There is many values which has to be checked. The same line of each timesteps (TS) must be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt fails in several different places; you assigned to `lines1` but ignored that, you try to use the `lines` list each and every iteration to produce a `max()` value, you never filtered out the non-numeric lines so trying to call `float()` on those would fail, and you never grouped the numeric lines correctly.

If your input file is so large, I'd not use the `max()` function but rather track the 3 maxima as you parse the file, testing each line against the maximum found so far.

Just read the file until you come across a `TS` line, then consume lines until there is a `SCALAR` line or the end of the file; those are numbers you want to get a maximum from which you then write out to the output file.

I'd preserve the format as much as possible otherwise:

```
maxima = [[float('-inf'), ''] for _ in range(3)]

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('TS'):
            # timestamp group, find maximum for the next 3 lines
            for maximum, line in zip(maxima, f):
                value = float(line)
                if value > maximum[0]:
                    maximum[:] = value, line

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    # write header to output file
    outfile.write('SCALAR\nND    3\nST  0\nTS      0.00\n')
    # write the 3 maximum lines:
    for value, line in maxima:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Note that `zip()` stops iteration as soon as one of the inputs is exhausted; by putting `maxima` first that means only 3 lines are read each time. I started the `maxima` list with `float('-inf')` because by definition, any other floating point value is going to be considered larger than that. Also, note that there is no need to strip newlines; `float()` doesn't care about leading or trailing whitespace, so any newline at the end of a line is ignored by that function.

The above tracks maxima as floating point values but leaves the original lines intact; the output file contains `256.5984`, `255.4946` and `257.0000` respectively, rather than rounded values.

This gives you output close to the original:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> sample = StringIO('''\
... SCALAR
... ND    3
... ST  0
... TS        10.00
... 0.0000
... 0.0000
... 0.0000
... SCALAR
... ND    3
... ST  0
... TS      3600.47
... 255.1744
... 255.0201
... 257.0000
... SCALAR
... ND    3
... ST  0
... TS      7200.42
... 255.5984
... 255.4946
... 255.7014
... SCALAR
... ND    3
... ST  0
... TS      10000.0
... 256.5984
... 255.1946
... 255.7014
... ''')
>>> maxima = [[float('-inf'), ''] for _ in range(3)]
>>> with sample as f:
...     for line in f:
...         if line.startswith('TS'):
...             # timestamp group, find maximum for the next 3 lines
...             for maximum, line in zip(maxima, f):
...                 value = float(line)
...                 if value > maximum[0]:
...                     maximum[:] = value, line
...
>>> outfile = StringIO()
>>> outfile.write('SCALAR\nND    3\nST  0\nTS      0.00\n')
34
>>> for value, line in maxima:
...     outfile.write(line)
...
9
9
9
>>> print(outfile.getvalue())
SCALAR
ND    3
ST  0
TS      0.00
256.5984
255.4946
257.0000
```

You could always use `outfile.write('{:.2f}\n'.format(value))` instead, if you did want to have output rounded to 2 decimals.

Comment: @MohamadRezaSalehiSadaghiani: you mean that the number of lines can vary? Do you know how many lines are there up-front when you open a file? If not, will the number of lines always be the same throughout?

Comment: Yes. But I solved it with another loop and with a count+ function.

Comment: can you please give me a hint how can I get the number of row with the maximum value? I want to find this row and open another file and read the 2 valuse of the second file and write into a new data!

Comment: @MohamadRezaSalehiSadaghiani: that makes things only slightly more complex; you'll need to track line numbers (use `enumerate()`) and when you test each line against the current maxima, store the line number together with the new maximum and `line` value.

Comment: Comments are not really a good method to talk about your code. If you have a follow-up question, perhaps it is better to post a new question about that.

Comment: Thanks. So I posted a new question.